# From where i can get the corresponding zip code with its appropriate State, city & of usa?

Tags: json, laravel, geolocation

On my Laravel project, I have to show the city, state with the corresponding zip code of the US. I need all zip codes, with city & state of USA. can anyone help me by providing JSON or CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

At what point do you need to fetch the data? You can find a multitude of api's which can help you with this.

Using the here.com api you could write a piece of code that fetches the address data:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html

This example is done using vuejs (https://morioh.com/p/af1a3deb6dda):
[image]

Comment: Thanks dear, for your answer. but I don't want to use API. I need in JSON or CSV format.

Comment: @Himelshipu I think that's possible, but not advisable. If you're thinking of creating a hobby project then I guess it's oke.

But if you're going to create a application which users are going to use, you're adding a lot of additional work. Because you would need to keep a list of addresses & maintain it as well. Is that something you really want?

A link I found was: 
https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses/tree/6b4b213d0732ee4b6b5e19e72e0cd0a3d82681ab

You could download all the data here and make CSV/JSON files of it.

Comment: thank you for your response. I will test with the link you have provided.

Comment: hey @Himelshipu, did you manage to get what you needed?

Comment: nope, @Humpff. I was unable to manage.